# How to use Update statement in DBT

Tags: dbt

How to use Update statment in DBT?
We created table in Snowflake using DBT but unable to use Update query to update the same table.

Is there any other way that we can achieve this , like other ELT/ETL tools?

Comment: dbt is designed to create idempotent transformations. Load the records into an upstream table and select only those required in the downstream model.

Answer (score 2):

i also run into this problem, and according this dic https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/configuring-incremental-models

```
{{ 
config(
    materialized='incremental',
    unique_key='payment_id',
    incremental_strategy='insert_overwrite'
)
}}

select
    ...
from orders o
    left join member m on o.member_id = m.member_id
    left join payment p on o.order_id = p.order_id
{% if is_incremental() %}
    where 1=1
        and p.gmt_updated >= (select max(payment_gmt_updated) from {{ this }})
{% endif %}
```

when source table payment updated ->"dbt run" -> my sink table got update (with same payment_id) too

Answer (score 1):

DBT does not allow to use DDL and DML Operation as easily as we can do in SQL. To Update the table on Snowflake Database that got created from Model inside DBT you can use Post_Hook configuration at top of model to call the Macro inside the post_hook.

eg.

**macro:**
{% macro UpdatebaseTable(DatasetKey) %}
update TableA
set
COL = ClnCOl
from TableA
left join TableB
on TableA.COl1= TableB.COl1
where TableA.DatasetKey = {{DatasetKey}};
{% endmacro %}

****Model:** Inside Model Call the Macro as a post_hook**

{{ config
(
materialized='table',
post_hook = UpdatebaseTable("'dataset_XXXX'"),
)
}}

Answer (score 1):

While it goes against dbt’s design and is not recommended, you can use the `pre_hook` or `post_hook` for merge / update / delete and other SQL statements. Just add the pre/post_hook and use the `{{ this }}` variable.

Example (you can put this in your `<model>.sql` file):

```
{{ config(
   post_hook=“UPDATE {{ this }} SET column_name=‘value’”
) }}
```

Keep in mind that when dbt runs, it will already compile the SELECT in the body of your model as:

- A MERGE (which will insert/update/delete) based on your SELECT filter (WHERE clause) when the materialization is incremental
- A `create or replace table` statement if materialization is not incremental

This means that ideally you should write the body of your query to include whatever logic you have in your UPDATE. You can also make a child model and put the UPDATE logic in its SELECT if you want to keep the transformations separate. This will make sure that your tables and transformations are idempotent.

Comment: I couldn't get the macro solution to work but moving the update to the post_hook worked perfectly... I was even able to put in multiple steps. thanks for this!

Comment: Having difficulty getting this example to work. In your example you added this below into the model file?          {{ config(
   post_hook=“UPDATE {{ this }} SET column_name=‘value’”
) }}                                                                        and then what do you add into your project.yml?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, there are ***many*** ELT/ETL tools you could use other than DBT, so let's not go down that route. A site like [StackShare](https://stackshare.io/) would be a better place to make decisions on your tools/stack.

However, it *is* possible to make DBT run any plain SQL statements (DDL, DML, etc.). DBT executes models using what they call "[materializations](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/materializations)". The key is to [create a custom materialization](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/guides/creating-new-materializations) for your needs.

If you don't want to go through the trouble of creating a custom materialization, you're in luck! I've created a [DBT package with such a materialization](https://github.com/marco-roy/DDO). The materialization is called `plain`, and you can find all the instructions in the repo/readme.