# Updating a PostgreSQL table through DBT

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbt, dbeaver

I have just gotten started with DBT, and I want to perform a simple update on a column:

```
update {{ ref('first_model') }}
set dt = TO_TIMESTAMP(dt::numeric)
```

However, this gives the error:

```
syntax error at or near "update"
  LINE 7: update "mydb"."my_schema"."my_table"
```

Which at least hints at me that I am referencing the table correctly. When I write

```
update "mydb"."my_schema"."my_table"
set dt = TO_TIMESTAMP(dt::numeric)
```

Directly into DBeaver, the query works, meaning the syntax should be OK.

Why is it not working on DBT?

Comment: I think this has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67870208/how-to-use-update-statement-in-dbt
DBT is not designed to run update statements, the concept is using intermediate models for complex data transformation and then get it materialized as we move into a higher layer.